# Flipping a Card triggered by Button

Tags: javascript, css

I want to have two cards defined, and flip them to toggle the view. I want an edit and save button to ultimately trigger the flip. But I'm stuck on triggering the button (still learning)

This example project [here](https://codepen.io/dbh21/pen/zYxrxEw) flips the card when the card is clicked but not the button itself. If I remove the action from the card and assign a `onclick="flipCard()"` function... I'm not sure what to define in that function.

This JS code I found in some examples online

```
$('.flip-card').on('click', 
  function(){
  //console.log($(this));
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped')
  }
)
```

I want to attach this functionality but on an onclick method.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you target things `$(...)`, and then inside the callback function optionally refer to them with `$(this)`.

So in your example, you target the flip card:

```
$('.flip-card').on('click', function(){
```

Then flip it:

```
$(this).toggleClass('flipped')
```

You can easily attach the trigger to the button, and the class update to the card. Remove the `onclick` bit, and just use jQuery.

```
// Target the button click...
$('button').click(function(e){
  // toggle the flip class
  $('.flip-card').toggleClass('flipped')
});
```

Or without jQuery it would look something like this, there are a couple more complexities with targeting *all* the buttons and their counterpart cards, but just as a pointer to get you started:

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector('.flip-card').classList.toggle('flipped');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## You can solve it multiple ways like as:

**Example-1.**

**Html**

```
<div class="flip-card mb-3 " onclick="flipCard(this)">
```

**Javascript**

```
function flipCard(el) {
   $(el).toggleClass('flipped')
}
```

**Example-2.**
just write jquery code here

```
$(document).on('click', '.flip-card',function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('flipped')
});
```

**===Thanks===**

Answer (score 0):

The listener has the `this` keyword in it, but it is different on every element the handler is invoked on. You should try something like this:

```
$('.flip-toggle').on('click', 
  function(){
    $(.flip-card).toggleClass('flipped')
  }
)
```